# How to retrieve only the month from Firebase Timestamp using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to compare the current month and the date stored in firebase as a timestamp. How can I retrieve only the month from the firebase timestamp so I can compare both the dates?

If you have some simpler version of comparing dates of firebase and javascript date then that is appreciated as well.

Comment: Please post your database structure

Comment: What have you done?
Is there any code of yours that can be presented?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase Timestamp objects can be converted to JS Date objects ([reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate)).

You could do this to get the month: `firestoreDocSnap.data().timestamp_field.toDate().getMonth()`

I'm not sure why you need just the month, but comparing date objects is really easy with Javascript. The Date objects supports comparisons with `<` and `>`.

`date1 > date2`

If you need to do equality operations, you have to call `.valueOf`
`date1.valueOf() === date2.valueOf()`

For more advanced date operations in JS, you can look into the [moment](https://momentjs.com/) library.